# How to install ImageMagick on XAMPP on my mac?

Tags: php, macos, xampp, imagemagick

For a school project I need to resize some images. The teacher tells us that we can use ImageMagick. But I don't success to install and use it on my computer.

I already install it through brew. That's it. All the tutorials are outdated, for windows.

EDIT: I forgot to say that i want to use it in php

Comment: After some search I've finally manage to resize my images using GD. There is my function:                                                                                                                             function resize_image($filename, $newwidth) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    $newheight = $height / ($width / $newwidth);
    $des = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($des, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($des, $filename, 100);
}

Answer (score -2):

TBH, installation can be confusing.

Tried with this tutorial and i was able to enable it.

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/349/how-to-install-and-enable-the-imagick-extension-in-xampp-for-windows

This one is not outdated.

But not sure why you want this for image resizing ?
If you using PHP? Much easier and cleaner to use library.

Edit after your edit: just use this PHP library: https://github.com/gumlet/php-image-resize

Comment: a windows install wont be much help for OP.

Comment: As you can see, the user said "For Windows".

Comment: and 'on my mac' ... he is also looking (wrongly) at tuts for windows.

Comment: You're right. This is a bit confusing. But anyway, @Louis, forgot about extension and use library. Much easier and better.